# Using JSch ChannelSftp : What file handling is required while calling ChannelSftp.cd(...) and ls(..) methods?

Tags: java, file, io, sftp, jsch

Below is the code, where channel object is initialized with :
(Sftp is an internal file. Let's assume changeDirectory() method is part of this class. )

```
    private void changeDirectory() throws SftpException {
    // jsch initializes
    Session session = jsch.getSession( "remote-username", "remote-host" ); 
    Channel channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
    channel.connect();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    // remoteDirectory is initialized
    sftpChannel.cd(remoteDirectory);
}
```

when this code is being executed, I am getting errors in below format :

```
Caused by: 4: 
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:359)
at com.dclear.cmn.cms.net.Sftp.changeDirectory(Sftp.java:139)
at com.dclear.cmn.cms.net.Sftp.receiveFile(Sftp.java:80)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:372)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2869)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2861)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2319)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
    ... 9 more
```

However when i dig deep into it, I do understand that to avoid this IndexOutOfBoundsException I have to take care of following :

len is negative, or len is greater than b.length - off
where :

```
b - the buffer into which the data is read.
off - the start offset in the destination array b
len - the maximum number of bytes read.
```

But, this is very internal code..How do I keep a check before calling cd(..) method on my file?? I have the file location & FileSize.

For some of the files I am also getting below exception :

```
 Exception: failed to get directory listing in SFTP protocol....
4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2187)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2202)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1566)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1527)
```

Which comes when the code calls :

```
List<LsEntry> ls = sftpChannel.ls(remoteDirectory);
```

Any inputs to avoid these random errors? I am sure they are because some file handling is missed and thus it is behaving differently for different files?

**FYI jsch version : Jsch\1.5\jsch-0.1.50.jar ChannelSftp (version 1.4 : 48.0, super bit)**

Comment: What version of JSch? What SFTP server are you connecting too (vendor, version)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl   jsch version : Jsch\1.5\jsch-0.1.50.jar
ChannelSftp (version 1.4 : 48.0, super bit)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did not get your question? Can you give me any example?

Comment: What is the SFTP/SSH server you are connecting to? If you do not know, enable [JSch logging](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html) and show us the log. Or (easier), use some GUI SFTP client (e.g. [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)), enable logging and show us the log.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Which logs you are referring to? As far as I know SFTP server is generic one..And I do not have the power to enable JSch Logging in this case, as the issue is coming on production scenario..Also I tried using your code locally, but it did not give me any other details. Is there any other thing we can do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88481/discussion-between-dish-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: What is generic SFTP server? OpenSSH? I doubt you would get the error with OpenSSH. Can you at least connect with WinSCP and show us [SSH implementation string from Server and protocol information dialog](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_fsinfo)?

Comment: Another method is to log a value of JSch `Session.getServerVersion()` *before* you call the `.cd()`.